# Amazon Athena - mismatched input 'STORED'. Expecting: <EOF>

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

I am just playing around with Athena, and I tried following this link
https://awsfeed.com/whats-new/big-data/use-ml-predictions-over-amazon-dynamodb-data-with-amazon-athena-ml

Create an Athena table with geospatial data of neighborhood boundaries

I followed the code based on the sample plus looking at the picture.
However, this is where I ran into issues and had to change the code to this based on the error messages Athena was giving me. Now the current error is mismatched input 'STORED'. Expecting: <EOF

FROM WEBSITE -

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE <table name    
"objectid" int,
    "nh_code" int,
    "nh_name" string,
    "shapearea" double,
    "shapelen" double,
    "bb_west" double,
    "bb_south" double,
    "bb_east" double,
    "bb_north" double,
    "shape" string,
    "cog_longitude" double,
    "cog_latitude" double)    
    ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
            FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' 
            LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
        STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
            'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
        OUTPUTFORMAT 
            'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
```

I kept getting errors around ROW FORMAT and have tweaked it below

```
WITH (ROW = DELIMITED
     ,FIELDS = '\t'
    ,LINES = '\n'
) 
STORED INPUTFORMAT 
    'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 
    'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
```

The error messages started at ROW and I've edited above. Now the error code relates to STORED so perhaps the changes I made are necessary. I am not sure. I am not very good with Athena so I was just following the guide and was hoping it would work. Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your SQL, the first line should be:

```sql
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE table_name (
```

There is a stray `<` in your example, table names can't have spaces, and there should be a `(` to start the list of columns.